Indefinite integral of $\log_x(x+n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I want to calculate
\begin{equation} \int \log_x(x+n) \,dx \end{equation}
for any constant $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
We can begin with
\begin{equation}
\int \log_x(x+n) \,dx  = \int \frac{ \ln(x+n) }{ \ln(x) } \,dx
\end{equation}
When I ask Wolfram Alpha to compute this indefinite integral, it says that no result was found in terms of standard mathematical functions. Can anyone enlighten me on any possible non-"standard" representation of this integral?

I dont know if that answers your question but for any continuous function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ an anti derivate is the function given by $F(x)=\int_c^xf(t)dt$, for any constant c.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#:~:text=The%20first%20fundamental%20theorem%20says,to%20any%20chosen%20end%20point.

For $n=-1$, there is a solution via infinite sum. Probably the same method will work here.

I would doubt if it matters that $n\in\mathbb Z.$ But this seems unlikely to have a closed form answer, if you write the integrand as $\frac{\ln(x+n)}{\ln x},$ it looks like no integral I know of.

If we define
$$I(x,s)\equiv\int_c^x t^s\dfrac{\ln(t+n)}{\ln(t)}\,\mathrm dt,$$
where $c$ is some arbitrary constant as long as the antiderivative doesn't diverge there, then, the integral we want to calculate is $I(x,0)$. If we differentiate that integral wrt $s$ it'll give
$$\partial_sI(x,s)=\int_c^x t^s\ln(t+n)\,\mathrm dt=\dfrac{x^{s+1}\log(x+n)}{s+1}-\dfrac{x^{s+2}\ _2F_1(1,s+2;s+3;-\frac{x}{n})}{n(s+1)(s+2)}+C_1$$
If we now integrate wrt $s$ we'll obtain
$$\small I(x,s)=C_2+C_1s+\mathrm{Ei}[(s+1)\log(x)]\log(x+n)-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^k\int\dfrac{s+2}{s+2+k}\left[\dfrac{x^{s+2}}{s+1}-\dfrac{x^{s+2}}{s+2}\right]\,\mathrm ds$$
where the last two integrals can be found here and here, and hence, after simplifying a lot, we end up with
$$
\small I(x,s)=C_2+C_1s+\mathrm{Ei}[(s+1)\log(x)]\log\left(n\right)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{n^k k}\mathrm{Ei}[(s+k+2)\log(x)]$$
Our goal integral is then
$$
\small \int\log_x(x+n)\,\mathrm dx=I(x,0)=\mathrm{Ei}[\log(x)]\log\left(n\right)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{n^k k}\mathrm{Ei}[(k+2)\log(x)]+\text{constant}$$
This answer is only valid for when $\left|\dfrac{x}{n}\right|<1$ though.

\begin{equation}
I=\int \log_x(x+n) \,dx  = \int \frac{ \log(x+n) }{ \log(x) } \,dx
\end{equation}
If $\left|\dfrac{x}{n}\right|<1$
$$ \log(x+n)=\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\, \frac{x^k}{k\,n^k}$$
$$x=e^t \quad \implies \quad J_k=\int \frac {x^k}{ \log(x) } \,dx=\int\frac{e^{(k+1) t}}{t}\,dt=\text{Ei}((k+1) t)$$

Sorry, I don't really understand what's going on here. Could you add some more words explaining what's happening?

@crxyz. What don't you understand ?
